# modify the_content() for page to display attachments with own style

Tags: attachments, the-content

I have for display attachmet on page this function

````php
$attachments = get_posts( array(
                            'post_type' => 'attachment',
                            'posts_per_page' => -1,
                            'post_parent' => $post->ID,
                            'exclude'     => get_post_thumbnail_id()
                        ) );

                if ( $attachments ) {
                    foreach ( $attachments as $attachment ) {
                        // Assuming $attachment_id contains the ID of the attachment
                        $attachment_metadata = wp_get_attachment_metadata($attachment->ID);

                        if ($attachment_metadata) {
                            // Get file size in bytes
                            $file_size = filesize(get_attached_file($attachment->ID));

                            // Convert file size to human-readable format
                            $file_size_human = size_format($file_size);

                            // Get file type
                            $file_type = $attachment_metadata['mime_type'];
                            //$file_type = get_post_mime_type($attachment->ID);
                            $file_url = wp_get_attachment_url( $attachment->ID);
                            $filetype = wp_check_filetype( $file_url );

                            // Display file size and type
                            //echo '<p>File Size: ' . $file_size_human . '</p>';
                            //echo '<p>File Type: ' . $filetype['ext'] . '</p>';
                            $link = wp_get_attachment_link($attachment->ID);
                            echo '<li>' . $link . '( ' . $file_size_human . ', ' . $filetype['ext'] .')</li>';
```                        }
````

this work how I want, but now I have duplicated attachment on a page because one is server wit the_content() function. Which is bet way to modify dipslay content for page with my attachment link display.

Comment: some notes, `exclude` and other `not` style operators are _extremely_ slow/expensive and very heavy on the server, it's much easier to add `if ( $attachment->ID === get_post_thumbnail_id() ) { continue; }` and could give a huge performance boost. The DB is optimised to give you what you want, it isn't optimised to exclude/hide what you don't want. Likewise set `posts_per_page` to a high value you know the server can handle, but never `-1`, your page can't display an infinite number of posts. Otherwise your Q appears to boil down to "how do I skip an attachment if it's already in the content?"